# What can cause to a failed database connection for a spring boot application other than incorrect datasource settings?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I have configured my spring boot application to run from a remote sql server database deployed to one of our environments with ip and port configuration below. And it works with no issue.

```
datasource.common.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
datasource.common.platform=mssql
datasource.common.username=${dbUsurname}
datasource.common.password=${dbPassword}
datasource.common.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.223.124.566:31567;databaseName=acc
```

But when I replace my connection  to another database instance that is deployed for another environment , even if I supply correct username , password and ip combination I get error.

```
    datasource.common.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    datasource.common.platform=mssql
    datasource.common.username=${dbUsurname}
    datasource.common.password=${dbPassword}
    datasource.common.url=jdbc:sqlserver://10.223.124.211:31567;databaseName=int
```

I get the following trace.

```
Cannot open database "int" requested by the login. The login failed. 
 ClientConnectionId:0dd4761b-8969-4848-96f8-c7ca41c48bf
```

I can connect to database with which I got error in spring application from mssql management studio with the given configuration and had no issue connecting it. Is there any setting for a database instance that prevents applications from connecting it other than username and password ?

Comment: Are `dbUsurname` and `dbPassword` exactly the same credentials that you, yourself, use in SSMS? The error is basically telling you that the username and password are correct, but that login doesn't have access to the `int` database. Or that there's no `int` database hosted on that instance.

Comment: I crosschecked credentials and compared it with credentials I used to login to SSMS. They are same. I searched for any additional configuration that can prevent my application connecting database but not ssms. Found nothing.